# How to render an array of spans inside a string in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of `span` elements that I need to render inside another static text.

Example final result: Put **3**, **1** and **2** in the right order `here the bold numbers are the spans`

Here is my code

```
generateQuestion() {
    const newState = { ...this.state };
    let numbers= newState.numbers.map((item, index) => <span style={{color: "red"}}>{item.number}</span>)
    let textQuestion = `Place the numbers ${numbers[0]}, ${numbers[1]} and ${numbers[2]} in the right order.`;

    return (
        <div>{textQuestion}</div>
    );
}
```

The problem is I'm getting this at render time `Place the numbers [object Object], [object Object] and [object Object] in the right order`

When I render `numbers` array directly I am getting the spans

```
return (
        <div>{numbers}</div>
);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Use a react fragment and not a template string? Or just put the text into the return?

Comment: Can you please write the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render objects inside string, the right way is to use jsx instead of string:

```
generateQuestion() {
  const newState = { ...this.state };
  let numbers= newState.numbers.map((item, index) => <span style={{color: "red"}}>{item.number}</span>)
  let textQuestion = <div>Place the numbers {numbers[0]}, {numbers[1]} and {numbers[2]} in the right order.<div>;

  return (
      {textQuestion}
  );
}
```

Comment: The variable `textQuestion` is unnecessary.

Comment: It works thank you , I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes it's just to make it more clear compared to using string

Comment: @Amine Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting the answer.